# Wordpress template name and PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

May sound like a strange question, but in wordpress page templates have the template name commented out at the top like...

```
/*
Template Name: Contact Us
*/
```

If 2 templates have the same template name they dont show up in the page template options, how does it read the template page name when its commented out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `get_file_data()` function.

**Read these:** [get_file_data](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_file_data) and [File Header](https://codex.wordpress.org/File_Header) and [this](http://phpdoc.wordpress.org/trunk/WordPress/_wp-includes---functions.php.html#functionget_file_data).

Answer (score 4):

> how does it read the template page name when its commented out?

I did not go through WordPresses source code, but I would assume that it does not parse it as php file, but as text file. It then goes through it line by line until it findes Template Name.

// Edit:

A bit more concrete information: Wordpress calls that a [File Header](http://codex.wordpress.org/File_Header).

The functions which load and parse this File Header may be found in wp-includes/functions.php, for example get_file_data. The comment to that function describes the constrains for the file header.

And it can be seen that Wordpress indeed reads it as normal file and extracts the information.

Comment: Hello its wordpress.Its syntax.Please search on google.